# Rails date select assigns month a value when blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

I am using Rails date_select as follows:

```
<%= date_select :user, :birthday, {:start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => 1910,:order => [:day,:month,:year], :prompt => { :day => 'day', :month => 'month', :year => 'year' }}, { :class => "default" } %>
```

When a user forgets to enter a value for the day or month and submit the form when the information is put into the model an error is generated. However the day and month fields also get assigned to 1. This results in the form showing 1 for the day field and January for the month field.

How can I stop this from happening?